# How to create a PDF with JSP and servlets in Java EE?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I've just started to create a website with Java EE (JSP, Servlet, ...).

I would like to how I can generate a PDF file from a JSP page in Java EE.

Comment: Neither JSP nor Servlets have anything on itself to do with any generation of PDF. You need some library (for example iTEXT, jaspers, xml-fo, etc) to do the generation based on your needs and possibilities and the jsp or servlet would be just the entry point for the generation.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it using `response.setContentType("application/pdf")`. The client has to have Adobe PDF reader installed, otherwise it will pop up a Save/Cancel window.

You might want to take a look at http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-serve-up-a-pdf-from-a-servlet.html